# How to get Google Map API Element to fill available space in Bootstrap column underneath heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, bootstrap-4

I have been racking my brain for hours trying to figure this out myself and scouring the web for answers but still haven't been able to figure this out. I'm hoping one of you guys could spare a few minutes to help me figure this thing out. Thanks!

I'm trying to have the Google Maps API element fill the available space beneath the "Visit" tag so that it will be able to resize itself as the viewport size changes. I have tried using various combinations of height: 100% and bootstrap classes but nothing seems to work.

[Here is a picture of what I would like it to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79TFv.png)

[Here is the link to the site I'm working on.](https://quintonmoran.com/chinese-take-in/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="col-12" style="height: 200px;">
<div id="map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;" class="h-100 w-100 rounded">
...
</div>
</div>
```

just add height in div that content map in your code as